# Custom CSS is missing in production build of create react app

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, production-environment

I have a ReactJS app using create-react-app, using the MUI library and a small amount of custom CSS. During development everything is fine, but when i create a production build with `npm run build` or `npm run-script build` for deployment, the custom CSS that i include in `index.js` is missing and not applied:

**index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

The `index.css` file is right next to it in the same directory. During my search for this problem, i saw that some people had this issue because they did not use a relative include path for the stylesheet. However, clearly i am using a relative path in my case (starting with `./..`). I also tried moving around a bit to see if it works with e.g. `../src/index.css` but it still is not included in the production build. Everything else, including the MUI library styles etc. works perfectly fine. Why is my `index.css` file ignored/not getting included in the production build?

Edit: I am building the production build on a NodeJS docker container as part of a multi-stage build before i move it to an NGINX container. `npm run build` does not work on the NodeJS docker container for some reason, so i have to use `npm run-script build`. I added this in case this is relevant.

Edit 2: I have moved `index.css` to the public directory and added a link tag to the `index.html`. The `index.css` is also successfully loaded in the production build now, but the style in it is not being applied.

index.html in public directory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css" /> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

index.css also in public directory:

```
:root {
  --qs-orange: rgb(238, 127, 0);
  --qs-blue: rgb(61, 192, 241);
  --qs-black: #333;
  --qs-purple: rgb(153, 0, 153);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.status-running {
  background-color: #66CDAA;
  color: white;
}

.status-failed {
  background-color: red;
  color: white
}

.status-default {
  background-color: var(--qs-blue);
  color: var(--qs-black)
}
```

Screenshot from the browser console to show `index.css` is loaded, but the style is not there in the elements (e.g. the headline element does not use the specified font-family. the body element also ignores it). Mind you, this works in the development version without production build. Font-family and all the stuff specified in `index.css` is applied to elements where it is not specifically overwritten.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: if I remember correctly your css needs to be in the public directory

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro I will try it out, but will this still work in dev mode? Is the include path the same?

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro When i move the CSS file to the public directory from src directory, i get the following error: "Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /index.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/."

Comment: you won't need to import the css to your file, remove the import and the styles should still apply

Comment: you just need to include in your index.html a `link` tag with reference to whatever file you want to access

Comment: something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />` with the path to yours obviously

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro I see, that makes sense! I moved it to the public directory and added a link tag to the index.html. The tag is also in the production build document, and the index.css does not result in any loading issues. However, the style is still not being applied to my elements despite the stylesheet being included. The CSS works perfectly fine in dev environment. Its not being overriden either, when i select an element the style from index.css is not even resolved to it (like font-family for body etc.)

Comment: can you please edit your question including your index.html and folder structure please, otherwise it is quite difficult

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro I added the content, please have a look! Thank you!

Comment: have you tried deleting your build folder and re-run npm run build after these changes?

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro Please excuse the late reply! Yes, i tried that. I also deleted the docker images i deploy it all and rebuild it countless times. Deleted cache in the browser. The problem still persists.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. create react served from a docker container. images and CSS correctly loaded in the browser but styles not applied at all. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/index.css" />` in the index.html

[image]

Comment: I did this, but the style is still not being applied in the browser although the css file is loaded.

Comment: Did you run npm eject?

Comment: What does that do? Sorry for the late response, i couldnt come back to this until now. It still does not work. It does not seem to be a cache issue with the docker container or in the browser.